# How to cross compile latest mono-3.2.0 for arm (hard float) platform on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: mono, cross-compilation

I have a Beagle Bone Black board. I have prepared a sd card for board. On sd card is prepared with Ubuntu-13.04-console-armhf-2013-07-22. My booard is booting form sd card succesfully. Now I want to install mono framework on that board. For that I want to cross compile latest version of mono from my host PC which is with OS ubuntu-13.04.
I tried with scratchbox 1.x.x but when I give command,

```
      $ make -j 8
```

I got the error: "hardfp-abi not yet supported."

How can I cross compile mono for my Beagle Bone Black..... ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mono port for hf yet. Use soft float distributive. However, there is patch somewhere for previous mono release 2.8. It will allow you to cross compile mono for hf.

Comment: Can you share the link of the patch that allows us to cross-compile mono for hf.